# How can I use translate.get in a service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-translate, ngx-translate

I have defined a service that sends to my layout the section in which the user is located as Home> User> Profile. I also have the language dictionary with Spanish, English and Portuguese languages. Suppose i have this json:

```
{
  "admin": {
    "log_out": "Log Out",
    "config": " configuration",,
    "master": "Teachers",
    "search": "Search log",
    "description": "Description",
    "duration": "Duration",
    "status": "Condition",
    "date_cr": "Creation date",
    "cancel": "Cancel",
    "upload": "File upload",
    "choose": "Select a file",
    "download": "Download template",
    "close": "Close",
    "up_pipeline": "Load pipeline",
    "search_pipeline": "Search pipeline",
    "client": "Client",
    "rule": "Rule",
    "periodicity": "Periodicity",
    "edit": "Edit",
    "delete": "Delete",
    "home": "Home"
  }
}
```

My service:

```
    private template: Layout[] = [
       new Layout('first', 'Home', ['/my/route']),
       new Layout('second', '', []),
       new Layout('third', '', [])
  ];
```

My model:

```
export class Layout {
    constructor(key: string,
                title: any,
                route: any[]) {
        this.key = key;
        this.title = title;
        this.route = route;
    }
    key: string;
    title: any;
    route: any[];
};
```

My problem comes when trying to translate these texts in the service with the `translate.get`. If I use `translate.instant('admin.home')` when loading the page it works but when refreshing it shows the `admin.home` key.

If otherwise I use `translate.get('admin.home').subscribe(text => text)` it shows me `[object Object]` but if I do `translate.get('admin.home').subscribe(text => {console.log (text})` it shows me the value of the key.
Where is the 'Home', is what is shown and where I have tried to use the translate.get without success.

How can I solve this and that when refreshing it does not show me the key instead of the value?

Comment: Hi @Brandon :) can you provide some additional code about the service where you are trying to translate the keys?

Comment: I have my model: 
export class Layout{
    constructor(key: string,
  title:string,
  route: any[]){
        this.key = key;
        this.title = title;
        this.route = route;
    }
    key: string;
    title: string;
    route: any[];
};
And my service: 
 private currentLayout: Layout[] = [
    new Layout('first', 'Home', ['/my/route']),
    new Layout('second', '', []),
  ];
Where is the 'Home', is what is shown and where I have tried to use the translate.get without success.

Comment: Hi @BrandonPacheco, Please provide complete json that you want to get translated.

Comment: @Brandon provide the code in the question above well formatted by editing it, it's hard to understand much with the comments :)

Comment: Oh im sorry jajaja

Answer (score 0):

in app.module.ts try:

```
import {APP_INITIALIZER, Injector, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {LOCATION_INITIALIZED} from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
    ...,
    providers: [
        ...,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
            deps: [TranslateService, Injector],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
export  function appInitializerFactory(translateService: TranslateService, injector: Injector): () => Promise<any> {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
  return () => new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {
    const locationInitialized = injector.get(LOCATION_INITIALIZED, Promise.resolve(null));
    locationInitialized.then(() => {
      translateService.use(window.navigator.language)
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(() => {},
        err => console.error(err), () => resolve(null));
    });
  });
}
```

also u can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299484/missingtranslationhandler-not-called)