# MissingTranslationHandler not called

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

part of my app.module.ts

```
import { MissingTranslationHandler, MissingTranslationHandlerParams, TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {

  handle(param: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
    console.log('handle', param);
  }
}

registerLocaleData(localeDe, 'de');

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      missingTranslationHandler: {
        provide: MissingTranslationHandler,
        useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler,
      }
    }),
  ],
  providers: [PreloadStrategy,
    {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: getUserLocale()},
    {provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeApp, deps: [SubscriptionService, AuthService], multi: true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

`handle(param: MissingTranslationHandlerParams)` doesn't get called.

Setting the `MissingTranslationHandler` on a component-level works e.g:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.scss'],
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.translateService.missingTranslationHandler = new class extends MissingTranslationHandler {
      handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams): any {
        console.log('handle', params);
      }
    };
  }
```

How can I get the `MissingTranslationHandler` app wide working?

Answer (score 0):

make file **translate-handler.ts**:

```
import {MissingTranslationHandler, MissingTranslationHandlerParams} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

export class TranslateHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
  private response = '';
  handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
    if (!environment.production) {
      console.error(`No Translation! Key: ${params.key}, Lang: ${params.translateService.currentLang}`);
    }
    return this.response;
  }
}
```

in **app.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            },
            isolate: false,
            missingTranslationHandler: [{provide: MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: TranslateHandler}]
        }),
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

for working **instant** method currectly [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67568476/7103430)